# How can I speed this LINQ query up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, entity-framework

I know that there's a much more efficient way to do this, using predicates, but being fairly new, I'm not sure exactly how to go about it..

```
List<HousingAssignment> list;

using (OEContext context = new OEContext())
{
    var query =
        from ha in context.HousingAssignments
        where ((ha.BedID == bed.ID) &&
                (((ha.CheckIn <= checkin) && (ha.CheckOut >= checkin)) ||
                ((ha.CheckIn <= checkout) && (ha.CheckOut >= checkout))))
        select ha;

    list = query.ToList();
}

return list.Count;
```

Comment: What makes you think the `where` expression is not a predicate?

Comment: Your query is a simple select statement with a where clause, I highly doubt there are any optimizations available that the compiler hasn't already done.

Comment: How is this too slow? Have you profiled it?

Comment: @Arran when you say profiled, do you mean Debug->Start Performance Analysis?  That's all I've done/know how to do at this point.

Comment: Your time is worth more than the time it took to post this question. Like evanmcdonnal says the compiler will do a lot for you. If its really slow, profile it, maybe add some indexes.

Comment: You could remove the `ToList()` call though I doubt that will have any significant impact on the performance. Currently that's the point where the query is executed, if you remove it you'll save the overhead of some cast(s) and instead the query will get enumerated when you call `Count(x => x)`.

Comment: @Jay I disagree. He stated he was new, so the answers he received here from experienced developers could be very valuable!

Comment: @Thomas Farley: Very true, just trying to warn against spending too much time worrying about performance like a lot of developers do.

Comment: @Jay Which I would consider valuable advice :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're merely returning the count, you can compute it in your query using the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468851.aspx) method:

```
using (OEContext context = new OEContext())
{
  var query =
    from ha in context.HousingAssignments
    where ((ha.BedID == bed.ID) &&
            (((ha.CheckIn <= checkin) && (ha.CheckOut >= checkin)) ||
            ((ha.CheckIn <= checkout) && (ha.CheckOut >= checkout))))
    select ha;

  return query.Count();  
}
```

This eliminates pulling the values from your database locally, storing into the list, then "throwing away" the results.  Instead, the count will get computed *on the server*, and you'll only pull a single number across.

You can also potentially speed up the query on the server with proper indexing of the `CheckIn` and `CheckOut` columns.

Comment: You might also need to add an index to the CheckIn and CheckOut fields in the database.

Comment: @TimB Added that to the answer, too.

Comment: This is what I was talking about..  I didn't need the data, just the number of records that matched the query..  I guess I was just tripping over myself..  Thank you :)  So simple..

Comment: @Glendale This will be a HUGE improvement if you just need the count, and not the data (which is what your code showed)